# Adding a game score to a tweet template

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a quiz type of website and I was wondering how I can change my code to add the score to the tweet

```
<button class="tweet-score" onclick="window.location.href="window.location.href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check%20out%20my%20score%20on%20this!%3A&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample-quiz.com/%2F">Share your score</button>
```

To display the score on the results html page, I just use `#score` with the CSS being as simple as:

```
#score{
    font-size: 100px;
    margin: 50px 0px;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function showScore(){
    var queryString = window.location.search
    var score = new URLSearchParams(queryString).get("score")

    $('#score').html(score + '/10')
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I can't figure out how to add the score to the tweet template. I can display it on the website, but not sure how to add it to the tweet. @madprops

Comment: I don't get it you want to tweet your score on Twitter by pressing a button on your app?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do @Tusharsaxena

Answer (score 1):

I think the quotes might be the issue. Instead try to bind a function.

```
 onclick="tweet()"

function tweet() {
   window.location.href = "theUrl"
}
```